# Capture everything but a particular structure using a single group

Tags: regex

I know the title is not the clearest but I did not know how to word it better.

What I want to do is to capture in a single group whatever is input, unless there's a particular structure around it, in which case just discard the structure and keep the rest.

I'll give some examples. Imagine the structure was `cap(.*)`, I'd like to have the following:

Input:

```
"cap(text)"
"cap(text"
"text)"
```

Output:

```
"text"
"cap(text"
"text)"
```

I'm stuck at something like

```
(?:cap\()?(.*)
```

But then it does not consider simultaneously both the "cap(" and the ")", and therefor examples 1 and 2 do not work.

Also

```
cap\((.*)\)|(.*)
```

doesn't work, as it separates the content in two groups, depending on the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace

```js
cap\((.*?)\)
```

with

```
$1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tIbgK0/1).

Here, `cap\(` matches `cap(`, the `(.*?)` capturing group matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and the `\)` part matches a `)`. The `$1` is a placeholder for Group 1 value.

If `cap` must be matched as a whole word, prepend it with a word boundary, `\b`:

```js
\bcap\((.*?)\)
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, what solved my problem was using ```cap\($1\)|(.*)```.

Comment: @GuilledeLima Where are you using this?

Comment: To remove one particular structure that may or not appear in a request. I do not want to remove parenthesis or the word "cap", though, if it is not an exact match. But yeah, with the regex I mentioned before, it works, I just wasn't aware that one can reference capture groups inside the expression itself.

Comment: @GuilledeLima In normal regex world, `cap\($1\)|(.*)` = `(.*)` and matches any string. That is why I am curious where you are using the regex.

Comment: Yeah, no, my bad, I misread a result, it is indeed not working. And I also misunderstood your previous answers, I'm sorry, you were completely correct from the beggining.